# Do I need to use MULTI/EXEC in Redis script

Tags: multithreading, lua, nosql, redis, atomic

I want to replace MULTI/EXEC operation in Redis, with Lua script call, and according to documentation of scripting in Redis:

> Redis uses the same Lua interpreter to run all the commands. Also
>   Redis guarantees that a script is executed in an atomic way: no other
>   script or Redis command will be executed while a script is being
>   executed. This semantics is very similar to the one of MULTI / EXEC.
>   From the point of view of all the other clients the effects of a
>   script are either still not visible or already completed.

As I understand I can drop MULTI/EXEC in this case and simplify my procedure, or is it more complicated, then this, and I still need to use it just in case? (For example for cluster environment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, with a Lua script, you can drop MULTI/EXEC, provided the MULTI/EXEC block was only used to enforce isolation (isolation as in ACID).

A cluster environment does not change anything, since MULTI/EXEC blocks only work at the instance level.

Comment: Are there still scenarios in which multi / exec may be needed? For example, what if the script throws an error somewhere in the middle? This would result in only a partial outcome being reflected in the database right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61711148/redis-how-to-make-eval-script-behave-like-multi-exec